# Cutting triangle into 2 and side length formula

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

Let ABC a triangle with base BC.
If we raise a line perpendicular to BC touching the edge A of this triangle. this  will divide it into two right triangles. With bases now BD and DC.

The book says: AC^2 = BC x DC.

What i don't understand is that if we just stretch the line BD, the above formula wouldn't be true. Or am I missing something here. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: If $ABC$ is not a right triangle, this is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some people commented, this can only happen if $ABC$ was a right angled triangle.

---

Here is proof that the formula is true:

If you have right angled triangle $ABC$, with base $BC$, and you have a perpendicular line to $BC$ touching the right angle $A$, then you end up with two triangles that are **similar** to the whole triangle and to each other.

Since the triangles are similar, the ratio of their corresponding sides are equal. So this means $\frac{AC}{DC} = \frac{BC}{AC} \implies AC^2 = BC*DC$.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.